# HttpPost in MVC AuthController

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am trying to set up a one time link authentication method.  I have an initial form in my Auth/Index where a user enters their username and password.  This generates a UID and passes it to another view

```
@model Hsbc.Marketing_Awards.Website.Models.AuthModel

<h2>EnterAuthenticationLink</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("AuthorizeOneTimeLink", "Auth", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress, "Enter one time link")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AuthenticationUrl, new { Name = "authenticationUrl" })
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

I want to submit this form but keep getting redirected to my Auth/Index view.  I'm assuming this is because I need to authorize the view in my web.config but I have tried doing that and it doesn't seem to work.

```
    <system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Auth" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="Home/Index"/>
    </authentication>
    </system.web>
  <location path="Views/Auth/EnterAuthenticationLink.cshtml">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Views/Auth">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

And the mothod I'm trying to access is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AuthorizeOneTimeLink(string authenticationUrl)
{
// Authorise link
}
```

IF I change the "AuthorizeOneTimeLink" action name to Index (so there are 2 Index actions on the controller), change the FormMethod to FormMethod.Get (and change the attribute in my new Index Action to [HttpGet]) then that works but will not pass penetration testing.

Comment: You don't authorise the view. Your authorisation is based on the controller action. try using the `allowanonymous` attribute instead

Comment: I had tried that.  It wasn't the authorisation that was the problem (the action was in the AuthController which is already authorised).  The problem was It had to be a HttpGet as it was a OneTimeLink.  My mistake.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now understand the problem.  It has to be a HttpGet (and will pass testing) as is a one time link sent to the user.  The user has to click on the link passing parameters to the application.  That has to be done using a HttpGet and not a HttpPost.